# how to convert database dates to strings with timezones

Tags: python, django, timezone

I have the following line of code

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(expire_date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z")
```

but it is not outputting the date with the timezone.

How can I change it so that it does?

Comment: Give https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/ a read

Comment: As a side note: It's very weird to call a method by calling the unbound method on the class and passing the object as the first parameter. Just write `expire_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z")`, like all the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) say:

> For a naive object, the %z and %Z format codes are replaced by empty strings.
>
> For an aware object: … If `tzname()` returns `None`, `%Z` is replaced by an empty string. Otherwise `%Z` is replaced by the returned value, which must be a string.

(The distinction between "naive" and "aware" is described in the introduction to the module.)

So, either you have a naive object (one that doesn't have a timezone at all), or an aware object that doesn't know how to name its timezone, or an aware object that thinks it knows how to name its timezone but returns an empty string.

Try logging `expire_date.tzname()`, `expire_date.tzinfo`, and `expire_date.tzinfo.utcoffset(expire_date)` and see what you get. (The [Available Types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types) section of the docs tells you how to interpret this.)

So, how do you fix it? Well, that depends on what exactly you're dealing with, but the most likely thing is that you need to call [`astimezone`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) or `replace` to imbue it with a timezone.

Or, more simply, just pass around UTC dates and timezones separately (or cram them together in a `tuple`, when appropriate), and write a wrapper that formats the pair of them into a string by concatenating a datetime string and a timezone string.